# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

There are a few conversation about this topic, but no one that really can help me.

Here is a page I am modifying, using Wordpress: http://www.cargo-websites.eu/demo-1/voorraad/

For a Javascript integration I am adding a script tag in the `<head>` tag of *header.php*:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://voorraad.cargo-websites.eu/demo-1/voorraad/js/include.js"></script>
```

As soon as I add this code, the page returns the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null
>           at responseIt (include.js:5)
>           at window.onresize (include.js:4)
>           at Object.trigger (jquery.js:3)
>           at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js:2)
>           at jquery.js:3
>           at Function.each (jquery.js:2)
>           at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js:2)
>           at a.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js:3)
>           at theme.js:78
>           at theme.js:94
>
> include.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null
>           at responseIt (include.js:5)
>           at window.onresize (include.js:4)

And consequently, the *header-img* on that page has disappeared.

I found a"how to" for fixing the problem but it's far beyond my knowledge. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: means the element you are referencing is not there...

Comment: The script is looking for id pageContent which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at that line (5) of include.js, we see it begins with this code:

> ```
> var height=d.getElementById('pageContent').scrollHeight;
> ```

That code attempts to access the *scrollHeight* property of whatever is returned by `d.getElementById('pageContent');` (note that in line 4 - the start of the function `responseIt()`, `d` is assigned the value `frame.contentWindow`, where `frame` is assigned the value returned by `document.getElementById('voorraadFrame')` i.e. the DOM of the iframe with `id="voorraadFrame"`).

In your browser console, you should be able to add a breakpoint on line 5 and reload to inspect the value being returned (see image below where I did it in Google Chrome).

[image: chrome debugger]

In order for that to return a DOM element, the HTML of the page needs to contain an element like this:

```
<div id="pageContent"></div>
```

The tag name could vary (e.g. could be *p*, *span*, etc.).